# Return multiple list values from method NSubstitute

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I read in the documentation that you can use Configure() in order to return different values every time a method is called. However, I am using NSubstitute 4.2.1 and I do not have access to "Configure()" on the API. I was wondering if there is any workaround to return different values.

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
var output = new List<List<MobileGetDocumentAuthorizationDto>>();
var counter = 0;
apiLayer.GetByIds(idStack).ReturnsForAnyArgs(x => 
                    {return output[counter++]; 
                    });
```

I add new values to output on a loop.

I would like to return different lists every time apiLayer.GetByIds() is called.

Thank you for your share of expertise on this one.

Comment: If you are using NSubstitute 4.2.1 it should include [`Configure()`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/configure/). I don't think you need it for this case though. @Nkosi's answers shows random values, or if hard-coded values are ok you can use [multiple values](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/multiple-returns/) syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in many different ways, but the following is a simple example using the following types

```
public interface IService {
    List<MyDto> GetByIds(int[] ids);
}

public class MyDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The sample test shows how the `Returns` function can be used to generate random results.

```
[TestClass]
public class NSubTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_Return_Multiple_ListValues() {
        //Arrange
        IService apiLayer = NSubstitute.Substitute.For<IService>();
        Random randomIds = new Random(9999);
        Random randomCount = new Random();

        apiLayer.GetByIds(Arg.Any<int[]>()).Returns(args => {
            var ids = args.ArgAt<int[]>(0);

            var count = randomCount.Next(ids.Length);

            var items = Enumerable.Range(0, count)
                .Select(_ => new MyDto { Id = randomIds.Next() })
                .ToList();

            return items;
        });

        //Act
        var list1 = apiLayer.GetByIds(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
        var list2 = apiLayer.GetByIds(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

        //Assert - FluentAssertions
        list1.Should().NotBeSameAs(list2);
    }
}
```

Every time the mocked member is invoked, it will return a different list generated based on the number of ids passed as input.